# Trying to retrieve child object from soql query

Tags: soql

I have the parent child relationship table where I provide the data for the job timings of employee on the basis of days(sunday,monday...)..but it will be stored as 30 days in calendar object as ( from as date time picklist, to as date time picklist,day as the weekday picklist)..now i want to get the from and to when i give the day and id of the employee.So as i do not require all 30 records i used group by day.
the From_c is also picklist values where picklist contains times from 7 am,7.30 am,8 am and so on.

this is the following **query**

```
Select c.Day__c,c.From__c,c.To__c  From Calendar__c c 
       where  c.Employee_Shift='a0bj00000006Z7vAAE' group by c.Day__c
```

I am getting the following **error**.

> Malformed query: field must be grouped or aggregated.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: shouldn't `Employee_Shift` also have a `__c` after it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details in your question? What are you trying to achieve?

When using group by with SOQL, aggregate functions can be used, but I don't think you can use other fields in your query
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm

Select c.Day__c,count(c.Id)  From Calendar__c c where  c.Employee_Shift='a0bj00000006Z7vAAE' group by c.Day__c

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's a problem with not using aggregate functions in query - you usually group objects to get cumulative sum or count of field values. Try adding a aggregate function to a query and see where it takes you.